# Trying to delete specific files and log the deletion

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete .txt and .xlsx files from my Temp directory and record that in a file in the temp2 directory.

If I remove

```
-include '*.txt, *.xlsx
```

And just put

```
*.txt
```

it works fine, but obviously only deletes one file type.

```
$LogFile = "C:\Temp2\DeletedFiles.txt"

$Path = "C:\Temp\"

$Files = Get-ChildItem $Path -Include '*.txt, *.xlsx'

foreach ($File in $Files) { 
    if ($File -ne $Null) { 
        Add-Content $LogFile $File.FullName
        Remove-Item $File.FullName | out-null}}`
```

Please help because I can't work it out!

Bonus points, if someone can explain what

```
if ($File -ne $Null)
```

does, that would really help because I had to steal that bit to make this work.

Comment: If you find a solution to your own Question, post it as an answer not as a comment.

Comment: Sorry, still working this site out!

Comment: No Problem! As long as one is willing to learn, errors benefit everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the path defined as follows:

```
$Path = "C:\Temp\"
```

Change it to `C:\Temp\*` (note the asterisk the end).

[image]

First command shows you what's in the directory. Second command implements the suggestion I gave. Third command is what you have now.

Comment: That did it. I could also have added -Recurse at the end of the Get-ChildItem line.

Answer (score 2):

For the -include switch you need to either specify a single item or an array of items. Try this:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem $Path -Include @('*.txt', '*.xlsx')
```

Bonus part:

```
if ($File -ne $Null)
```

checks if the variable $File is not empty.